# Mobx Uncaught SyntaxError in Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron, mobx, mobx-react

this is the code I am running with mobx:

```
import { observable, decorate } from 'mobx'
class store {
  infoData = ''
};
decorate(store, {
  infoData: observable
})

export default new store
```

I have a:

  `"devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "^2.0.7",
    "electron-react-devtools": "^0.5.3",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mobx": "^4.3.2",
    "mobx-react": "^5.2.5",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
  }`

These are the errors I am facing upon running the application :

```
 C:\Users\shaha\Documents\electron-react-starter-kit\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:558 Uncaught SyntaxError: C:/Users/shaha/Documents/electron-react-starter-kit/app/components/mobx.js: Unexpected token (4:9)
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (C:\Users\shaha\Documents\electron-react-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4454)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\Users\shaha\Documents\electron-react-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1761)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseClassProperty (C:\Users\shaha\Documents\electron-react-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:2571)
    at Parser.parseClassProperty (C:\Users\shaha\Documents\electron-react-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:6157)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseClassBody (C:\Users\shaha\Documents\electron-react-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:2516)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseClass (C:\Users\shaha\Documents\electron-react-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:2406)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:\Users\shaha\Documents\electron-react-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1843)
    at Parser.parseStatement (C:\Users\shaha\Documents\electron-react-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:5910)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlockBody (C:\Users\shaha\Documents\electron-react-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:2268)
```

Despite cloning different boilerplates for react electron, I was unable to get passed this error.

How can I avoid them ?

Comment: can u push your code to github with package.json so that I can replicate it to see the issue

Answer (score 0):

What is missing is [babel-plugin-transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/)